# How do I tell the custom onSuccess function to stop the upload spinner in Ant Design Upload component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have this code:

```
render() {
    const props = {
      onChange: this.handleChange,
      multiple: true,
      name: 'datafiles[]',
      defaultFileList: this.initialState.fileList,
      listType: "text",
      onSuccess: (resp, file, xhr) => {
        file.status = 'done';
        const newDatafile = {
          filename: file.name,
          s3ObjectKey: `${this.props.userId}/${this.props.datasetId}`,
          filesizeBytes: file.size
        }
        this.props.saveNewDatafile(newDatafile, (saveError, savedJob) => {
            //Yadda yadda
        })
      },
      showUploadList: {
        showPreviewIcon: true,
        showRemoveIcon: true
      },
      customRequest: customRequest
    };
```

As you can see, I am using the `customRequest`. If I don't pass the `onSuccess` function, then the component works properly on success. But when I pass it, the progress bar reaches the end, but it still shows the spinner as if it was still uploading.

[image: pesky spinner before the filename]
Pesky spinner before the filename

How do I tell the Upload component that the upload finished? I tried with the `file.status = 'done'` in a sad attempt to fix it, but no luck. I need the custom `onSuccess` function so I can call the `saveNewDatafile` function.

Comment: I didn't see an `onSuccess` prop in the docs ?

Comment: Seems like the property is `spinning` @ https://ant.design/components/spin/#components-spin-demo-delayAndDebounce

Comment: @Dane, In the docs, if you go to the customRequest docs (https://github.com/react-component/upload#customrequest) you can see that you can pass a onSuccess function there, which works and it is called here https://github.com/react-component/upload/blob/master/src/AjaxUploader.jsx line 134

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan This does not relate at all with my question, it's a different component and the normal behaviour in the Upload component is that the spinner disappears along the progress bar, not that it stops spinning.

Comment: Ok saw it... it was not here https://ant.design/components/upload/

Comment: could you host the Minimal Working App somewhere like in a fiddle or something. it could be easy to debug the real issue..

Comment: @Tyrannogina How did you access the progress bar?

Comment: Hi @cocoPuffs, what do you need to access the progress bar for?
I wanted it to be updated, which I accomplished using the onChange function and updating the percentage. I also dispatch an action from this onChange so I keep the redux state tree updated.

If what you need is to edit styles of the progress bar, you'll probably need to do a wrapper component or something, I am not that good with styling... ^_^U

Comment: @Tyrannogina Yea I just figured it out last night, pulling my hair out for a week because I couldn't see in the docs the percent property off 'file' could be set to change the progress bar.

Comment: Yeah, been there, hahaha! Congrats on figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using the onChange function instead of the onSuccess function, and adding a conditional `if (file.status === 'done')`

Answer (score 1):

After digging into src of upload component, I think it's impossible to use `customRequest` to control upload status, we have on way to set status in callback `onSuccess`.

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/d89ffcc5b22cd7a722e1d9740f2f6f04c014f09b/components/upload/Upload.tsx#L77-L97

That said, I found an example in [the repo of antd](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/upload/demo/upload-manually.md) to upload manually.

It seems antd prefer callback onChange instead of onSuccess/onError directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
const preventRequest = () => false;

<Upload beforeUpload={preventRequest}>
  <Button>
    <Icon type="upload" /> upload
  </Button>
</Upload>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.